# Change location for straight.el working directories?

Tags: init-file, config, configuration-files, straight.el

I’d like to put my dotConfig files into DropBox, including my `.emacs.d` folder.  I’d like to use these across computers and across OS’s.  I’ve split out part of my `init.el` into per-computer files (whose location is specified with an environment variable) to help its this.

Is there a way to tell `straight.el` to save the working files somewhere other than `~/.emacs.d/straight`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cursory look at the sources (I do not have the package installed) suggests that `straight-base-dir` is the operative variable:

> Directory in which the straight/ subdirectory is created.
> Defaults to `user-emacs-directory'.

So customize it and see if it works.

Comment: This worked!  I was using an older version so it wasn't present (or, therefore, documented) in the straight.el that I had installed.  I switched to the 'develop' branch and it's now working great.  Thanks!

Comment: Nice! Frankly, it was an untested guess, so I'm glad it worked.

Comment: Looks like I spoke a bit too soon.  It mostly works but straight.el and org end up in the normal place instead of straight-base-dir.  I ended up using a symbolic link to a folder outside of Dropbox and then marking the link as hidden from Db.

Comment: That's where all the code *should* be installed - but you mostly want the data files out of there (unless you are sharing them too of course). I'm not sure what you mean by "org": do you mean things like org.el (the code)? Or do you mean your Org mode files (the data)? If the former, I don't see how it makes a difference. If the latter (and you don't want to share them with other computers), just put them somewhere else and adjust things like `org-agenda-files` and friends.