# change location of straight.el lockfile

Tags: package, straight.el, lock-files

I'm using `straight.el` as a package manager in emacs and would like to make my settings and packages portable and identical over several machines

That's why I like to put the `default.el` file under version control. I already have a git repository that manages `dotfiles` and would like to put it there. I generate symbolic links with `gnu stow` out of this dotfile repo to make the process convenient when I move to a new machine.

To avoid littering of this repository I set

```
(setq user-emacs-directory "~/.cache/emacs/")
```

Otherwise `straight.el` would put the downloaded repos inside my dotfile repo and I would get a dirty repo by just installing packages.

If I execute `M-x straight-freeze-versions` I now get the following lock file

```
~/.cache/emacs/git/straight/versions/default.el
```

which would be the file to put under version control.
If I would go back to my `stow/dotfile` approach I now would have the `.cache` folder/package littered by stuff that gets stored in the `.cache` folder.

Is there a way to only change the lock file location of `straight.el` or is there another approach to putting `default.el` under version control.

I found [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/60507/change-location-for-straight-el-working-directories) but as I understand that does something similar to the `user-emacs-directory` but specifically for `straight.el` stuff, which has the same implications as before.

Comment: Thx, that stuff somehow got lost. :(